# Export boolean columns from the telerik RadGridView in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, export-to-excel, telerik-grid, radgridview

The item source to the RadGridView is class, the grid has about 20 columns out of 2 are bool columns. In the bool columns if the value is true we are displaying image.

```
              public bool IsPassed {get;set;}
              pulbic bool HasStructNumber {get;set;}
```

when I export to excel and if the above values are true want to display a string like "*****". How to do this ?

```
public static string ToExcelML(this GridViewDataControlsource,IEnumerable items, bool includeHeader, bool includeFooter);
```

called this method from RadGridView instance.

```
      RadGridView rg;
     rg.ToExcelML(grid.SelectedItems, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not override the headers you need to change the e.Value only when the e.Element is ExportElement.Cell.

```
private void clubsGrid_ElementExporting(object sender,GridViewElementExportingEventArgs e)
  {
   if (e.Element == ExportElement.Cell)
     {
       var column = e.Context as GridViewDataColumn;
       if (column != null && column.Header.ToString()=="IsPassed")
         {
            if (e.Value == true)
             {
               e.Value = "Yes";
             }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: for more explanation look into this http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-boolean-columns-from-radgridview#5ZkDac6gbEKf4HUVTPz6fg